# how to convert a date string like this MM/YYYY to 01-MM-YY

Tags: oracle, date

I have a column and its type is string and stores date something like this 03/1996
I want to convert that to 01-MAR-96?

how can I achieve that in ORACLE

Comment: Those that fail to learn from history are doomed to repeat it.  Please do not use 2-digit years.

Comment: And you lose the ability to use several handy date functions and ability to do date arithmetic on that column, unless you use a `to_date(bogus_date, 'dd-MON-YY')` on that column, incurring a performance hit. The optimizer will also make stupid assumptions on that column, assuming there are values like '12-32-18' ... '12-99-18' etc between '12-31-18' and 01-01-18'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SQL> select to_char(to_date('03/1996', 'MM/YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY') from dual;

TO_CHAR(T
---------
01-MAR-96
```

Based on that (if by convert you meant changing the data in the table):

```
update table tableX set columnX = to_char(to_date(columnX, 'MM/YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY');
```